# how do you create nested shared objects in multi processing in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

How do you create nested sharable objects in multiprocessing? - such as a nested list?

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    processors = 5
    '''This is what I am trying to replicate'''
    # MASTER = [[[], [], []] for _ in range(processors)]

    MASTER = manager.list()

    for number in range(processors):
        MASTER.append(manager.list())
        index = MASTER.index(number)

        for _ in range(3):
            MASTER[index].append(manager.list())

    print(MASTER)
```

I recieve a ValueError when trying to run this code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/engli/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/16/04/15/07/newtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    index = MASTER.index(number)
  File "<string>", line 2, in index
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    processors = 5
    MASTER = manager.list()

    for number in range(processors):
        MASTER.append(manager.list())

    for x in MASTER:
        x.append(manager.list())
        x.append(manager.list())
        x.append(manager.list())
```